# LuaTeX glyph node: how to find out a ligatures's components

Tags: luatex

With `luatex` glyph nodes representing a ligature have a `components` field of type `node` which is supposed to ``point to the ligature components''. I fail to understand how I can fetch the components using this link, any help would be much appreciated.

For ``standard'' ligatures ff, fi, fl, ffi, ffl which have a fixed code (U+FB00 to U+FB04) it is easy to make a table that solves the problem, but what about less common ones like ct, ft, … ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the head of a node list so looks (for ff) as if you had an hbox with two f

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setbox0\hbox{fish diff --- abc}

\directlua{
glyphn=node.id('glyph')
h=tex.getbox(0)
print('\string\n=====')
for n in node.traverse_id(glyphn,h.list) do
  if (n.components) then
    print(n.char .. ' ' .. utf8.char(n.char))
    for nn in node.traverse_id(glyphn,n.components) do
      print('>> ' .. nn.char .. ' ' .. utf8.char(nn.char) )
    end
  end
end
print('\string\n=====')

}
\end{document}
```

Prints:

```
=====
64257 ﬁ
>> 102 f
>> 105 i
64256 ﬀ
>> 102 f
>> 102 f
8212 —
>> 45 -
>> 45 -
>> 45 -

=====
```

showing the glyph numbers of the components for `fi`, `ff` and `---`

I added printing of the characters as well as the numbers, although that will print nonsense for ligatures using non Unicode slots, it helps read simple cases

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was missing!